# How can we estimate the predictive interval in Lasso regression

Tags: bayesian, lasso, posterior

Dear Community members,

I am using lasso to solve an inverse problem (a Fredholm) which I can reframe as

\begin{equation}\min_{\mathbf x ~~{\rm with}~~x_n\geq 0} \ell_{\rm Lasso}(\mathbf x, \lambda)\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}\ell_{\rm Lasso}(\mathbf x, \lambda)= ||\mathbf A \mathbf x-\mathbf b||^2+\lambda ||\mathbf x||_1\end{equation}

with $\mathbf A$ an ill-conditioned matrix. I understand that the Lasso may be understood as the maximum a posteriori estimate of the following pdf and that it can be derived from Bayesian arguments, meaning that

\begin{equation}
p(\mathbf x|\mathbf b, \lambda)\propto \exp\left(-\frac 1 2\ell_{\rm Lasso}(\mathbf x, \lambda)\right)
\end{equation}

While I can sample from the ridge posterior or an elastic net without problem (I can do exact HMC following the work of [A Pakman, L Paninski - arXiv preprint arXiv:1208.4118, 2012](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4118) since it is basically a truncated Gaussian), the sample from the Lasso posterior is a bit problematic since $\mathbf A$ is near singular. I would be grateful if anyone could let me know if and how I'd be able to sample the Gaussian.

Comment: Are you sure that lasso is the right tool for this? If $A$ is nearly singular, one would tend to favor an elastic net or ridge solution.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure at all but the lasso allows me to track the characteristic features (timescales) of the system so I think it has some practical value. In fact, I have tried ridge and I think that we should try elastic net (non naive) too.

Comment: Well, the point of ridge regression is to stabilize coefficient estimates in situations with singular or nearly singular $A$. I don't know what you mean about timescales and characteristic features, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am testing both lasso and ridge and for some reason the lasso works.